# How do I know when it's time to make a temporary variable a member variable instead?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, c++14

Whenever I'm working on scientific projects in C++, sooner or later I find myself calling methods that need to allocate big temporary objects in memory (e.g. vectors/matrices) needed to compute the final result.

My question is then: when should I consider making these temporaries member variables of the class instead? My reasoning is that if they are members already, then there is no need to allocate new memory every time a method is called that needs to access them to store temporary data. At the same time though, the more memory I allocate for "big" member variables, the harder it might be to find suitable chunks of memory for performing other tasks.

I know that in general member variables should represent some sort of property associated to a class, but memory-wise it seems advantageous to create more member variables at first glance.

Of course this is assuming that pointers or references are already being used where the address of a variable can be used.

I wasn't able to find any clear answer. I hope this is clear, please ask for any clarification if needed.

Comment: There is no clear answer. Ideologically, if the variable is not needed to describe the state of the object, it should not be a member. But then practicalities get involved, for example your not wanting to re-allocate storage repeatedly. I'd also look into `static` local variables.

Comment: To be clear, you allocate once, do a big expensive calculation, deallocate, and return the result?  Does the size of the allocation change between function calls?

Comment: Another thought: [Memory pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool)

Comment: @NathanOliver exactly. I find myself calling methods that allocate memory for holding temporary variables like matrices (needed for intermediate calculations). These intermediate values are then somehow used to obtain the final result I need to return. At that point, the method returns and the temporary variables are not needed anymore, so that memory is freed up.
The answer to your second question is "sometimes". In cases where it does change between calls, I doubt it would be wise to create member variables. When the size of allocation is constant, however, it sounds convenient.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for your reply. What would be the convenience of using a `static` in this case though? And thank yo for the link you provided, I am looking into it right now.

Comment: can you give a concrete example? Imho without the quesiton is too broad / opinion based.

Comment: The storage persists and it's still a local variable so you don't have to worry about stuff like the Rule of Three, not for the buffer at any rate.  Unfortunately it makes the function totally non-re-entrant.

Comment: Be careful that you aren't optimising prematurely. If the objects are temporary, you want to keep them as local vars. ONLY once your app is working AND a profiler tells you that the allocations are costing you a reasonable percentage of total work done, should you consider alternatives.

Comment: I suggest that before you start to reuse objects to avoid memory allocations, you should profile your code and see whether the time to allocate really is significant. That would depend on how exactly you use the memory.

Comment: @giacomo-b Okay.  For the size changing case, I'd do what you are doing currently and profile.  If the performance is good enough, then you're done.  For the cases where the size doesn't change, I'd try both ways and go with which one is faster.  If it is a tie, or close enough to be a tie, then I suggest keeping the "temporary" method as to not waste space when it is not needed.

Comment: @GavinLock you're right, it's probably wiser to profile the code later. But nonetheless I still wonder if there is a rule of thumb in case this was indeed a performance limitation. I guess there is no clear answer though.

Comment: @walnut agreed on that.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess trial and error in the end would be the best option to really know the truth.